# How can I load a taxonomy term into a views preprocessing hook?

Tags: views, 8, theming, taxonomy-terms

I have a strange situation where I need to insert a non-product entity into a view result of products. The view appears on a taxonomy term page, and I want to add some field content from the term into the view result. I can get the term ID from the view in a `template_preprocess_views_view` hook, but I can't load it with something like `$term = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->load($tid);` to get the field content. I guess I'm wondering if this is the right way to do this, it's sort of an unusual requirement in my experience.

Comment: what's the error when using `$term = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->load($tid);` ?

Comment: There aren't any errors, but nothing is assigned to the variable.